# Can't get jQuery to match heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't get the heights of my buttons to match using the following code. I have jQuery imported. Any ideas? I'm sure it's something obvious I'm overlooking.

```
<div class="row-fluid " id="imageUploadBtns">
   <div class="span2 offset2" id="imageUploadBtn"> 
      Some Text 
   </div>
   <div class="span2" id="imageUploadBtn">
      ...
   </div>
   <div class="span2" id="imageUploadBtn">
      ...
   </div>
   <div class="span2" id="imageUploadBtn">
      ...
   </div>
</div>

<script>
   boxes = $('#imageUploadBtn');
   maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
   Math, boxes.map(function() {
       return $(this).height();
   }).get());
   boxes.height(maxHeight);
</script>
```

Comment: Why are there multiple elements with the same `id` attribute?

Comment: It would probably make sense to use the selector `".span2"` because using `#` will only return one element (maximum), since `id`s should be unique. Using ".span2" is another thing they have in common that will actually return the full list of matched elements.

Comment: Why not change your id="imageUploadBtn" to class="imageUploadBtn"?  That would make more sense than having non-unique IDs which is bad form.

Comment: ah yes, sorry my mistake. I knew there was something obvious. I have other ".span2" in the code else where. How can I just match heights for these four?

Comment: `$("#imageUploadBtns .span2")` will get the elements with class `span2` inside the div with id `imageUploadBtns`.

Comment: @Archer have tried that - still no joy

Comment: Then your html is not as shown above.  That code will do exactly as described.... [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LJhsm/)

Comment: @Archer Or even better: http://jsfiddle.net/LJhsm/1/

Comment: Thanks - I had omitted some code from my question - Divs are resizing with the answer below. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't be using the same ID for more than one attribute.
you probably get only one element from $('#imageUploadBtn')
try using 
$('.span2')
instead

Comment: try
$('#imageUploadBtns .span2')

Comment: try setting the display of those spans to inline-block

Comment: I had omitted some code from my question - that was the issue. Your answered worked - Thanks